# Compare sign of two doubles in Java

Tags: java, math, jvm, double, equals

I have 2 doubles, what's the best way to check that they have the same sign?

For now I check

```
Math.signum(d1) == Math.signum(d2)
```

but I'm not sure it is correct for doubles as Math.signum() itself returns a double value.

Would the above be ok if I already checked both numbers are not near 0?

Comment: What if some argument is zero ?

Comment: In my specific case I check if one of them is 0 before this stage because the logic is different. In general I guess it depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works, because returned value is always `param / Math.abs(param)` (`x / |x|`), so a number from `{-1.0, 0.0, 1.0}` (0.0 in case input is 0 to avoid division by 0) and according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) it works for double.

If you're unsure, you can always check: `d1 * d2 >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just prove if d1 * d2 > 0.